# Profile parameter login/password_downwards_compatibility meaning?

Tags: security, passwords, sap-basis

I am currently evaluating the use of the `login/password_downwards_compatibility` parameter, but I can not fully understand it.

In what cases is it used? And what risks would it have associated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly don't you understand [in official documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/EN/4a/c3f18f8c352470e10000000a42189c/frameset.htm) for this parameter?

Values from 0 to 5 shows strictness of SAP password hash generation and evaluation during logon, starting from the most strict (**0**) to the most legacy way (**5**).

You **do not need** to change the default value (aka **1**) of the parameter unless:

- your system is a central storage system of [CUA](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/bf/b0b13bb3acd607e10000000a11402f/frameset.htm), where landscape consists of old systems
- your system is very old itself, i.e. SAP Netveawer ≤ 7.00 (SAP_BASIS 700)

You **must not** touch this parameter at all unless you are a professional BASIS. 
Period.